# expression is of wrong type from a weak reference cursor

Tags: dynamic, plsql, oracle10g, ref-cursor

I am attempting to get a ref cursor to run a dynamic query and return the results. here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE CUR_DATA IS REF CURSOR;
    OUT_DATA CUR_DATA;
    SQL_Statement       NVARCHAR2(8000);
BEGIN
    SQL_Statement := ' SELECT * FROM dual ';        
    OPEN OUT_DATA FOR SQL_Statement;
END;
```

why does this give me an error saying : expression is of wrong type? This ref cursor is weakly typed isn't it? Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mentioned in the Oracle document that the `Select` Statement support `CHAR`, `VARCHAR2`, or `CLOB` (`not NCHAR or NVARCHAR2`).
If you want to implement with `NVARCHAR` then the only solution i know is to `translate`  USING `CHAR_CS` argument converts char into the database character set. The output datatype is `VARCHAR2`.

```
DECLARE
    TYPE CUR_DATA IS REF CURSOR;
    OUT_DATA CUR_DATA;
    SQL_Statement       NVARCHAR2(4000); --declare this as VARCHAR2
    SQL_Statement_var       VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    SQL_Statement := N'SELECT * FROM dual ';        
    SQL_Statement_var := TRANSLATE(SQL_Statement USING CHAR_CS);
    OPEN OUT_DATA FOR SQL_Statement_var;
END;
```

`No errors.`

If `NVARCHAR2` is not mandatory ,then try to create with basic data types provided.

```
DECLARE
    TYPE CUR_DATA IS REF CURSOR;
    OUT_DATA CUR_DATA;
    SQL_Statement       VARCHAR2(4000); --declare this as VARCHAR2
BEGIN
    SQL_Statement := ' SELECT * FROM dual ';        
    OPEN OUT_DATA FOR SQL_Statement;
END;
```

References:

[Translate...USING](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions197.htm)

[Open For Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/openfor_statement.htm)

Comment: NVARCHAR2 or VARCHAR2 Doesnt matter to me, and I'm not even aware of a difference between the two. Thanks for the tip! I was banging my head against the wall on that 1

Comment: @Adamantine:Yes then go with the Second approach using varchar2